# Как получить username или fullname пользователя по номеру телефона modx revo api?

Tags: php, modx, revo

Пытаюсь найти **username** (**желательно**) или хотя бы **fullname** пользователя по номеру телефона,

```
$tell = $_POST['tell'];

//найти юзера по номеру телефона
if ($profile = $modx->getObject('modUserProfile', ['mobilephone' => $tell])) {
$getUser = $profile->getOne('User');
//номер телефона в системе находится
$userName = ""; // а вот как теперь в профиле, в котором нашелся номер телефона, получить username/fullname?
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто `$userName = $getUser->get('username');`